# Report Viewer Web Part Alternatives in SP2013

Tags: web-part, 2013, reporting-services, project-server

We have a need to upgrade from SP2010+PWA to SP2013+PWA. Our database server will be SQL Server 2008 R2.

According to [Technet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/gg492257.aspx), the SQL 2008 R2 Reporting Services add-in for SharePoint isn't compatible with SP2013 (it only plays nicely with SQL2012's reporting add-in);

`For SharePoint 2013, you can ONLY use the SQL Server 2012 SP1 version of the Reporting Services add-in for SharePoint.`

Our requirement is to show a report in a page of SharePoint. Previously we had used the Report Viewer Web Part but now we need an alternative method.

What alternative ways are there to embed a report within a SharePoint (2013) page?

Comment: What do you plan to do with SSRS?  Leave it in a 2010 version, or move it to a native (non-integrated) instance?  There used to be a regular html view that was available which could be hosted in a web page viewer web part.

Comment: Hi Mike, ta for the words. Our SSRS is already in Native mode c/o some other applications on the server. I do believe our 2013 deployment is getting it's own DB instance on a new DB server so I'm hoping we may get an upgrade to SQL 2012.  I have been thinking that the Page Viewer webpart may be a suitable workaround & have suggested that to the dev however I just want to check for any more elegant options!

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be to use Excel Services to display a report. (details would depend on your specific requirements and data sources though).

Comment: Thanks @lwbecker2. I think the trick to that is that we already have an existing SSRS report that we're trying to retain. I must admit I don't know much about SSRS & Excel reporting services, is it a trivial operation to move an SSRS report to Excel services or is it a complete redevelopment effort?

Answer (score 0):

In your case,PerformancePoint Dashboard designer is the best alternative choice to host Native SSRS within SharePoint 2013.

In this article, you can found the same real scenario related to PWA environemnt [to View and Explore a Native Mode Report via PerformancePoint Report within SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/08/29/view-and-explore-native-mode-reports-using-performancepoint-report-in-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 0):

We run SSRS 2008 R2 native mode and SP 2013.  We display our reports in SharePoint 2013 in iframes using the Page Viewer web part.

Answer (score -1):

As an update, we're going to try this:
- install SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services (SSRS) only on the SP box
- Configure the reporting service to use the SQL 2008 R2

This should bring in the required webparts. The 'iffy' part of all this is the license ramifications (which we'll know more about on Monday) + whether it's possible to run this config & have it still be supported when using a standard SQL edition rather than enterprise.

Will update when we have some answers.